# "The answer to question 4" or "the answer to the question 4"?

Tags: grammaticality, definite-article

Consider the examples below:

> 1. What was the answer to question 4?
> 2. What was the answer to **the** question 4?

I'm sure that the definite article in the sentence 1 is used correctly.
My question is that can we use the definite article before the word question? Or if we can't, why? Because the question 4 is definite.
I don't understand why the definite article isn't used in the sentence 1.

Comment: We ordinarily treat designations like *Question No. 4* or *Figure C* or *Chapter 14* *Room 2347* as names, because just like personal names they designate entities which are unique in the current discourse context. Such names do not take definite articles.

Comment: @StoneyB Would you consider posting your answer in the answer section rather than the comment section? :-)

Comment: @snailplane I was pretty sure this had been addressed somewhere before ...